# SQL - Missing comma error

Tags: sql

I've looked at the other entries on this topic and they're not helping me figure out what's wrong with my code.  Can someone please tell me what's wrong here?  I keep getting a "missing comma" error.  My code is...

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders
(  ORDER_NUMBER,
   TO_DATE(ORDER_DATE,'Month DD,RRRR'),
   ORDER_TOTAL,
   CUST_ID, 
   STAFF_ID)

VALUES 
(
   5680,
   'June 12,2004',
   159.78,
   145,
   9)
```

Thanks,
Lisa

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to do with the column list?  It shouldn't have a formula in it. You can put the formula into a `select` statement instead of `value`:

```
INSERT INTO copy_f_orders(ORDER_NUMBER, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TOTAL, CUST_ID, STAFF_ID)
    select 5680, to_date('June 12,2004', 'Month DD,RRRR'), 159.78, 145, 9)
```